# Midpoint circle without duplicates?

Tags: c++, algorithm, bresenham

I have some code to generate grid coordinates (`SDL_Point` just contains two `int`s for x and y) with a circle shape:

```
std::vector<SDL_Point> circle(const SDL_Point & start, const int radius)
{
    int x{ radius }, y{ 0 };
    int xChange{ 1 - 2 * radius };
    int yChange{ 1 };
    int rError{ 0 };

    std::vector<SDL_Point> circle;
    SDL_Point coord;

    while (x >= y)
    {
        /*  Due to circle's symmetry, we need only to calculate
            points in the first 45º of the circle.
        */

        coord = { start.x + x, start.y + y }; // Octant 1.
        circle.push_back(coord);
        coord = { start.x - x, start.y + y }; // Octant 4.
        circle.push_back(coord);
        coord = { start.x - x, start.y - y }; // Octant 5.
        circle.push_back(coord);
        coord = { start.x + x, start.y - y }; // Octant 8.
        circle.push_back(coord);
        coord = { start.x + y, start.y + x }; // Octant 2.
        circle.push_back(coord);
        coord = { start.x - y, start.y + x }; // Octant 3.
        circle.push_back(coord);
        coord = { start.x - y, start.y - x }; // Octant 6.
        circle.push_back(coord);
        coord = { start.x + y, start.y - x }; // Octant 7.
        circle.push_back(coord);

        ++y;
        rError += yChange;
        yChange += 2;

        if (2 * rError + xChange > 0)
        {
            --x;
            rError += xChange;
            xChange += 2;
        }
    }

    return circle;
}
```

This works ok, but I noticed some coordinates are added twice when copying from one octant to another (clearer gray in the picture):

[image: midpoint circle]

Is there a known way to avoid having those duplicates or should I just check before adding them to the `vector`?

I would like to know what is the most efficient way to do it. I haven't found any answer, I guess it's not usually a concern when printing plain color circles.

EDIT: I need the vector as output.

Thanks! :)

Comment: Does it have any *actual* performance or correctness impact? If not, then ignoring it is always a valid option.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you consider what your code is doing, there are two cases that generate duplicates:  when `y` is 0 (along the edges of your diagram), and when `x == y` (the diagonals in the circle).  You can add a check before the appropriate `coord` calculations for these conditions to exclude them.

For example,  `coord = { start.x + x, start.y + y };` and `coord = { start.x + x, start.y - y };` generate the same values when `y` is zero.

Comment: Uhm, you're right, maybe that's the easiest solution. Thanks, I'll try!

Answer (score 3):

You could use a container that enforces uniqueness, like

```
std::set<SDL_Point>
```

and then use the insert method instead of push_back.

Comment: I was thinking about doing that, but is it really efficient? I'm never sure. And I would need a vector as output anyway, so I would have to copy the contents of the set.

Comment: Yeah -- it's efficient. At least as efficient as whatever else you'd do to ensure uniqueness in a vector.

Comment: Any particular reason you need a vector? Maybe that can be accomplished with set as well.

Comment: Well, because I have other functions that also output a vector of points and all of their outputs will be managed similarly. But maybe I should make them all sets... I'll think about it :)

Answer (score 0):

Implementing 1201ProgramAlarm's answer goes like this:

```
push([x, y])
if (x != 0) push([-x, y])
if (y != 0) {
  push([x, -y])
  if (x != 0) push([-x, -y])
}
if (x != y) {
  push([y, x])
  if (x != 0) push([y, -x])
  if (y != 0) {
    push([-y, x])
    if (x != 0) push([-y, -x])
  }
}
```